# Source information is missing from the debug information for this module

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, debug-symbols, crash-dumps

I'm trying to debug a dump file (.DMP) in Visual Studio 2013. I clicked on "Debug with Managed only" action and cannot get pass this error:

> **Source not available**
>
> Source information is missing from the debug information for this module
>
> You can view disassembly in the Disassembly window. To always view disassembly for missing source files, change the setting in the Options dialog.

I have tried:

1. Providing a path for the symbols to load (.PDB)
2. Enable/Disable Just My Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't look at my call stack. It was showing that I was in .NET code and complaining because it doesn't have .NET source code to show me (which I don't expect it to). If I click within different lines in my call stack, I can navigate and it shows more specific errors.